# "Installer crashed" during install process on a dual boot UEFI Windows 8.1 64-bit laptop

Tags: dual-boot, usb-drive, uefi, laptop, microsoft-windows

I've encountered a couple of problems whilst trying to install Elementary OS alongside my existing Windows 8.1 installation. I've resolved one but hit a wall with the other. I really appreciate any help, I really want to use this OS.

## Main Problem

> Installer crashed

After choosing the installation type (Install elementary alongside Windows Boot Manager), a dialog appears that says "Copying files...". After some time this changes to "Installing system". A couple of moments later I receive the error message above.

I took a bunch of photos of the screen throughout the process that you can view [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B8nySlDXyPwqLXVtZkMwNU1TTFE?usp=sharing).

You can expand the "Installing system" dialog to see extra detail, and the last message displayed before / as the error occurs is:

```
.install_misc.InstallStepError: Plugin language failed with code 4
```

## Other Problems

- Error immediately at beginning of installation.

  > Sorry, elementary 0.4 has experienced an internal error.

  Resolved this by running opening a terminal and running `sudo apt-get remove ubiquity-slideshow-elementary`, then restarting the installation.
- Left click on touchpad only works on some things. For example it works on icons on the dock, but not on the icons in the top right.

## Other Details

- Created bootable USB with Rufus.
- Disabled secure boot.
- Disabled fast startup.
- Disabled fast boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it. I found [a bug reported on launchpad that described my problem](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1579454), it is apparently due to the installer (ubiquity) trying to open a file that it needs super user permissions for. The work around is to run the installer under `sudo`.

To do this I selected "Try elementary without installing". Once booted there is a shortcut with the title "Install Elementary OS", I decided to just modify this shortcut by opening a terminal (`command + T`) and issuing the following commands:

```
cd /usr/share/applications
nano ubiquity.desktop
```

Now scroll down and add 'sudo' to the beginning of the execution property.
Save the file. Click it (you may have to look in the application launcher to find it).

Alternatively you may be able to just open a terminal and execute `sudo ubiquity`, but I've not tested this.